# Converting a string to a JSON for a HTTP POST request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, slack

I'm trying to return a json file from a HTTP POST request from Slack. I am using netcoreapp3.1 along with the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet. Right now my HTTP POST function looks like this.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> SlashCommand([FromForm] SlackSlashCommand request)
    {
        var retVal = new JsonResult(GetBlock());

        return retVal;
    }
```

GetBlock() is a function that returns a class that I created. This works currently, but everytime I want to modify the json that it returns, I have to modify that class. I would really love to just have a json in string format that I can copy and paste into my code and then return to Slack in json format.

Is there a way to do this? I've been trying to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str); but I'm using it incorrectly. From what I understand, that function takes in an string and converts it to an object. I need to take in a string and convert it to a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult json.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: How is modifying the JSON different to modifying the string format?

Comment: Honestly, it would help you tremendously If you read up some docs on differences in strings, jsons, what is a json, classes and lastly, what does it mean to serialize and deserialize. Your question is quite generic without much info to go with to give you an answer

Comment: Please do provide a minimal reproducible example of your code. All methods and code necessary to do your work again

Comment: Thank you. That is true, I need to read more on this.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option is to use an anonymous type, which will be less vulnerable to becoming invalid JSON (a simple typo in your JSON string could render the entire block of JSON unreadable):

```
var data = new
{
    blocks = new object[] {
            new {
                type = "section",
                text = new {
                    type = "plain_text",
                    text = "Hello!",
                    emoji = true
                }
            },
            new {
                type = "divider"
            },
            new {
                type = "actions",
                elements = new object[] {
                    new {
                        type = "button",
                        text = new {
                            type = "plain_text",
                            text = "Help"
                        },
                        value = "helpButton"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
};

return new JsonResult(data);
```

Produces:

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text":
            {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Hello!",
                "emoji": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "divider"
        },
        {
            "type": "actions",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text":
                    {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "help"
                    },
                    "value": "helpButton"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CCLNY23980)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

This is my JSON in string format:

```
string str = "{\"blocks\": [{\"type\": \"section\",\"text\": {\"type\": \"plain_text\",\"text\": \"Hello!\",\"emoji\": true}},{\"type\": \"divider\"},{\"type\": \"actions\",\"elements\": [{\"type\": \"button\",\"text\": {\"type\": \"plain_text\",\"text\": \"Help\"},\"value\": \"helpButton\"}]}]}";
```

And then this is my function:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SlashCommand([FromForm] SlackSlashCommand request)
{
    var retVal = new JsonResult(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(str));

    return retVal;
}
```

This works quite well. Sorry if I didn't give too much info.

Comment: So you want to send a fixed JSON message every time? You never want to change it dynamically, etc?

Comment: Correct, because it will be the same message every time. That's why converting the string was the easiest way.